# JdbcSQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException when inserting new entry after schema generated from class and initial data loaded from file

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, crud-repository

I have a spring boot project with an h2 database.

I have an entity class from which the schema is to be generated:

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "NAMES")
public class Name {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    public String name;

    public Name(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

And I have a `data.sql` file:

```
insert into names (id, name) values (1, 'Alex');
insert into names (id, name) values (2, 'Bob');
```

my application.properties is:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

The application starts up just fine, I can confirm with localhost:8080/h2-console that the data is loaded into the database.
But I cannot save new data into the table with

```
//public interface NameRepository extends CrudRepository<Name,Long> {}

@RestController
@Service
public class MyController {

  @Autowired
  private final NameRepository nameRepository;

  @PostMapping("/triggerError")
  public ResponseEntity<Void> trigger() {

    Name newName = new Name("Chris");
    nameRepository.save(newName);
    return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
  }
}
```

The error message is:

```
could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [\"PRIMARY KEY ON PUBLIC.NAMES(ID) ( /* key:1 */ CAST(1 AS BIGINT), 'Alex')\"; SQL statement:
insert into names (name, id) values (?, ?) [23505-210]];
```

I assume that this means that spring wants to insert the new name at id=1, not realizing that ids 1 and 2 are already in use. I guess the right parameters to `@GeneratedValue` could fix it but I do not understand what they mean and which one to choose.

## Trial and error:

`@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)` is the default, see above.
`@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)` same error
`@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)` same error
`@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)` different error:

```
...
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: NULL not allowed for column \"ID\"; SQL statement:\ninsert into names (id, name) values (null, ?) [23502-210]
...
could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
```

So apparently it is not the annotation, but something else.

I'm giving up, heres my MRE: https://github.com/timo-a/duckpond-spring-backend/tree/debug/saving

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@Shankar Ghimire is partially correct. This is both a Hibernate bug and a data.sql issue. Update your Hibernate version to 5.6.5:

```
implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'){
  exclude group: 'org.hibernate', module: 'hibernate-core'
}
implementation 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.6.5.Final'
```

and since you are using the h2 auto_increment, you should remove the id in your data.sql

```sql
insert into names (name)
values ('Alex'),('Bob');
```

The sequence won't increment otherwise leading to Unique index or primary key violation.

---

By the way, your repository uses Integer as your PK whereas your entity uses Long. And since the question is tagged as JPA, use :

```
public interface NameRepository extends JpaRepository<Name,Long> {}
```

And you insert data in a table named "scores" but I assume it's a typo.

Comment: "scores" was a typo, I've corrected it, thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the hint about `Int`/`Long` as well, I've fixed it

Comment: I use CRUD to keep it simple, I've corrected the tags. I've added more code to my question and tried `@Transactional` but with no change in behaviour.

Comment: Sorry, I just wrote a reprex: https://github.com/lookslikeitsnot/stackoverflow-71101007/tree/main and found out using transactional hid the problem instead of solving it. Using H2 v2.1.210 and `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)` solves the issue. (Switching version in POM : 2.0.202 <= version <=  2.0.206 triggers the issue)

Comment: Thanks for the effort! I was using H2 v2.1.210 all along, so that cannot be the problem. I've also made a MRE: https://github.com/timo-a/duckpond-spring-backend/tree/debug/saving (I've adapted the structure to your example) unfortunately I still get the error

Comment: I, once again, was mistaken. Looking at the dependency tree, maven uses H2 v1.4.200 by default. I thought I explicitly imported v2.1.210... I created a PR for your repo, could you check it and confirm it fixed the issue ?

Comment: I confirm: It works! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug on hibernate and specific to h2 database.
https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-14985

you can use `id BIGINT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY DEFAULT ON NULL PRIMARY KEY` column definition as a fix.

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(columnDefinition = "id BIGINT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY DEFAULT ON NULL PRIMARY KEY")
private Long id;
```

Comment: I tried this but got:
`Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLNonTransientException: Unknown data type: "ID"; SQL statement:`  
`Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of URL [file:.../build/resources/main/data.sql]: insert into scores (id, name) values (1, 'Alex'); nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "NAMES" not found (this database is empty); SQL statement:`
`Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "NAMES" not found (this database is empty); SQL statement:`

Answer (score 1):

It helped me:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(columnDefinition = "bigint not null constraint user_pkey primary key")
private Long id;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).